# deal with boost variant and boost function

Tags: c++, function, boost, variant

I would like a vector to hold differents kind of boost::function, so, I tried a variant :

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <vector>

void a(int, int)
{}


void b()
{}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    typedef boost::variant<boost::function0<void>, boost::function2<void, int, int>> v;

    std::vector<v> c;

    c.push_back(boost::bind(&a, _1, _2));
    c.push_back(boost::bind(&b));

    auto& function = boost::get<boost::function2<void, int, int>>(c[0]);

    function(4, 5);
}
```

But I've this error :

```
   /usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1515:28: error: call to member function 'initialize' is ambiguous
              initializer::initialize(
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1692:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<boost::function0<void>, boost::function2<void, int, int>, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>::convert_construct<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > > >' requested here
        convert_construct( detail::variant::move(operand), 1L);
        ^
```

I didn't find any help to deal with theses error

(and other compiler output)
https://ideone.com/QEdlyF

Thanks !

Comment: It's a bit funny you claim "I didn't find any help to deal with theses error" when you basically [took the sample code _verbatim_ from my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602229/boost-function-template-errror#comment47353868_29603173). Where I show how to get this work using explicit casts. :)

Comment: Yes, because I adapted (kind of copy-past) your example to my code, I got this error and i didn't find your explicit cast :(

Comment: Okay. I'm glad you found it now. Saves me the trouble of making the sample here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor for Boost Function is pretty liberal in what it can accept. This results in there being no "best" constructor amongst the elements types of the variant.

You'll have to explicitly cast.

Then again, it's probably even easier to just hide the knowledge about types alltogether (since the helpful parts are ambiguous anyways) and use Boost Any.